# VBA merge cells with loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to merge cells  two in columns A and B, for example like bellow, and so as long as I have records, below is my code but does not work and does not merge cells do not know what the problem. thanks

```
.Range("A5", "A6").Merge
.Range("A7", "A8").Merge
.Range("A9", "A10").Merge

.Range("B5", "B6").Merge
.Range("B7", "B8").Merge
.Range("B9", "B10").Merge


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim xlMerge As Range
Dim xlMergeJ As Range

For i = 5 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row Step 2

        Set xlMerge = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1))
        With xlMerge
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End With
    Next i

For j = 5 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row Step 2

            Set xlMergeJ = Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j + 1, 1))
            With xlMergeJ
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           End With
        Next j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you're after this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row Step 2
            With .Cells(i, 1).Resize(2)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Cells(i, 2).Resize(2)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

or its shorter option:

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row Step 2
            With .Range(.Cells(i, 1).Resize(2).Address & "," & .Cells(i, 2).Resize(2).Address)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ZdravkoLukic, did you get through it?

Comment: @ZdravkoLukic, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to people trying at helping you. Thank you